# Expressing a function in terms of $(D_{1}f)(x-y,x+y) $ and $(D_{2}f)(x-y,x+y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> **Question:**
> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Define $F(x,y) = f(x-y,x+y)$. Express $D_{1}F(x,y) + D_{2}F(x,y)$ in terms of $(D_{1}f)(x-y,x+y)$ and $(D_{2}f)(x-y,x+y)$.

**My attempt**
Let $u = x-y$ and $v = x+y$
$$
(D_{1}F)(x,y) = \frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{u}} = \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{u}} \cdot \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} + \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{v}} \cdot \frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}} = \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{u}} \cdot 1 + \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{v}} \cdot 1
$$

$$
(D_{2}F)(x,y) = \frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{v}} = \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{v}} \cdot \frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}} + \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{u}} \cdot \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}} = \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{u}} \cdot 1 + \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{v}} \cdot -1
$$
After adding the results we get

$$2 \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{u}}$$
This is $2(D_{1}f)(x-y,x+y)$

Please correct me if I am wrong.